# Looking for "high verbal" quotation from David Gerrold

Tags: story-identification, david-gerrold

A few years ago (around 2016) David Gerrold had a story in *The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction* that briefly talked about being "high verbal".

If anyone remembers it and can let me know where this appeared, it would save me a lot of searching.

Or, even if not that specific one, other references to the topic would be appreciated too.

Comment: By "high verbal", do you know whether it's referring to extensive vocabulary? Being a good talker? Functional autistic?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, its a about how some people think, such as thinking only in words, seeing each individual word with all its possible meanings (e.g. puns).

Comment: Starting in 60s, but mainly in 1970s, there was tremendous focus, testing, and studies especially pre-college on subject of High Verbal characteristics. I seem to recall a primary goal was identifying people who could code well and then facilitate them through primary education guidance counseling systems to steer consideration into such fields of work and study after high school.

Answer (score 5):

[This interview](https://sundial.csun.edu/67034/arts-entertainment/former-star-trek-screenwriter-david-gerrold-releases-play-to-csun/) has David Gerrold using that phrase:

> DS: Going through school, what were your career goals?
>
> DG: I wanted to write and direct (film). Writing actually came very easy to me because I’m what they call ‘high verbal,’ I just talk too much. But if you want to write you have to read, and if you read a lot you’re going to end up wanting to write. And I was a big science fiction fan, I was reading a novel a day, so by the time I hit college I had already read the entire backlog of science fiction magazine and novels, which at that time you could do because it wasn’t a very large library it was only maybe a couple thousand books. I started in high school, so I was pretty well caught up. Then this show called Star Trek comes on and I’m looking at it saying, “Well I know script-format because I learned that at USC, and I know story structure and I know science fiction and a lot of people don’t, that’s why we get such lousy shows, I’m going to submit an outline to them.” They liked the outline, they said come back for a second season and I sold them a script called “The Trouble with Tribbles.” That was my senior project here at school. It was a great way to graduate, turning pro.